# How to get real password (before encrypt) when register a user?

Tags: security, password, encryption

I just need to get real password (before encrypt) when user is registering. I need to save that password in another table. How I access the real password before encrypt?

The reason for it is, I am doing a research about passwords.

Comment: This kind of research is usually done with password lists from known site breaks. Their size guarantees at least some statistical value. What you are trying is not research. Besides that, passwords are not encrypted in WordPress, they are hashed. Encryption is reversible, hashing is not.

Comment: grrr, you could have just written "i want to collect emails and passwords" :( It is bad enough that you can get such lists, don't see any reason for us to encourage such a reckless behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what research you are doing, but you can hook into `user_register` and get submitted password using `$_POST` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into `user_register` to get the submitted password from the `$_POST` request:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
       /* do something with $_POST['password'] */
    }

}
```